# Increment variable in bash for loop

Tags: bash, scripts, curl

Trying to create a script using `curl` to probe multiple URLs for updated information.
Currently, I'm using individual commands for each URL, which I am trying to shorten lines of codes by using increment variables in a `for` loop.
What I have at the moment: (dummy urls as examples)

```
#!/bin/bash

url01="https://askubuntu1.com"
url02="https://askubuntu2.com"
url03="https://askubuntu3.com"
url04="https://askubuntu4.com"
url05="https://askubuntu5.com"

for i in {01..05}
    do
        url=$((url$i))
        curl $url 2>&1| grep 'askubuntu' >> output.txt
done &
```

**Error Output:**

> line 10: https://askubuntu1.com: syntax error in expression (error token is "://askubuntu1.com")

**Expected result:**
command input to bash shell for each of `curl` queries pipes to `grep` then outputs to "output.txt".

> *curl "https://askubuntu1.com"
>
> curl "https://askubuntu2.com"
>
> .
>
> .
>
> curl "https://askubuntu3.com"*

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment `url=$((url$i))` attempts to evaluate `url$i` as an *arithmetic expression* - this is not appropriate here. What you could do instead is make use of *variable indirection*:

```
for url in url{01..05}
do
  curl "${!url}" 2>&1| grep 'askubuntu' >> output.txt
done
```

However it would probably cleaner to use an array:

```
#!/bin/bash

urls=(
  "https://askubuntu1.com"
  "https://askubuntu2.com"
  "https://askubuntu3.com"
  "https://askubuntu4.com"
  "https://askubuntu5.com"
)

for url in "${urls[@]}"
do
  curl "$url" 2>&1| grep 'askubuntu' >> output.txt
done
```

---

You could also loop over the *indices* of the array `${!urls[@]}` - which would give you the desired incrementing integer variable from which to construct a sequence of numbered output files ex.:

```
for i in ${!urls[@]}
do
  printf -v output 'file%02d.txt' $((i+1))
  curl "${urls[i]}" 2>&1 | grep 'askubuntu' > "$output"
done
```

The `$((i+1))` is because bash array indexing starts from `0` - if you don't mind the outputs being `file00` through `file04` then you can use plain `$i`.

For the version based on variable indirection, you could do either

```
for i in {01..05}
do
  url="url$i"
  curl "${!url}" 2>&1| grep 'askubuntu' > "file${i}.txt"
done
```

or

```
for url in url{01..05}
do
  curl "${!url}" 2>&1| grep 'askubuntu' > "${url/#url/file}.txt"
done
```

Comment: cheers, the first error is a typo... which I have corrected to "{ }" (thanks!)

Comment: confirmed that both of your solutions worked! @steeldriver I would use this as the best answer to my question.
additionally, what if I would like to output files to have increment variables per each url? example:
output01=file01
output02=file02
... output05=file05?

Comment: @danh please see updated answer

Comment: thank you!@ steeldriver, this is very helpful and easy to understand.