# Variable inside another variable in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to delete some files with loop. But can't figure out the way of doing it. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1=/path/to/file
dir2=/path/to/file
dir3=/path/to/file

for i in 1 2 3
do
   rm ${dir$i}
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment variable in bash for loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296046/increment-variable-in-bash-for-loop)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible with `eval`, but I'd strongly advice not to use that!

Use an array instead:

```bsh
dirs=(
"/path/to/file1"
"/path/to/file2"
"/path/to/file3"
)

for i in 0 1 2
do
    rm "${dirs[$i]}"
done

# OR simply loop all the array values:

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
    rm "$dir"
done
```

Note, that arrays are 0-based.

Comment: Can I make variables of the paths and use the variables inside array?

Comment: You mean like `dirs=("$dir1" "$dir2" "$dir3")` ?

Comment: Yes. Can I do this?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in bash with *indirection*

> ```
>    If  the  first  character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and
>    parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of indirection.  Bash
>    uses the value formed by expanding the rest of parameter as the new pa‐
>    rameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in  the  rest  of
>    the  expansion,  rather  than  the expansion of the original parameter.
>    This is known as indirect expansion.
> ```

but it requires an intermediate variable ex. given:

```
dir1=/path/to/file1
dir2=/path/to/file2
dir3=/path/to/file3
```

then

```
$ for i in 1 2 3; do d=dir$i; echo rm "${!d}"; done
rm /path/to/file1
rm /path/to/file2
rm /path/to/file3
```

You could eliminate the intermediate variable by looping over strings `dir1` `dir2` `dir3` using brace expansion:

```
for d in dir{1..3}; do echo rm "${!d}"; done
```

The same feature is available in `zsh` using the `P` modifier:

```
% for i in 1 2 3; do d=dir$i; echo rm ${(P)d}; done
```

See [Use a variable reference "inside" another variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41418/65304)

Comment: Cool. I would still prefer arrays though ^^ Probably also not very portable.